# How to route local traffic over switch?

Tags: networking, switch

I'm just cabled up at home but haven't got any way of verifying that gigabit speed can be reached. As I've only got one laptop with one network card, one cable, and one switch, I'm kind of stuck.

I'm using a tool that you can start as a server or as a client to send data from one box to another. I would like to send and receive on the same Windows box.

I guess if I use my network local IP address, my Windows 8.1 PC will just route traffic internally. Is there some way of forcing the traffic to go to the switch and back again?

Comment: What would send the traffic back?

Comment: What is the sound of one hand clapping?

Comment: The switch? I just need to trick my PC in thinking that the target IP address is not a local one, so that the trafic heads outbound. The switch just reflects the trafic back again.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would need two network cards to do that.

Find a friend or neighbour with a gigabit capable machine & buy a second cat6 cable (your current cable is labelled as cat 6 isn't it? Otherwise it might not work at gb speeds anyway).

You don't really need any software to test by the way, you will see the speed of the connection by looking at the connection properties. With 2 PC's you could also copy a large file to show the real-world speed but remember that this may be limited by other factors such as disk speed and other activities on the PC.